# Nested VMs networking : QEMU in a Vmware machine

Tags: networking, nested, vmware, qemu

I've read many guides and blogs what couldn't solve this for me.

I am trying to build an environment the includes:

--Windows 10 as the Host, with VMPlayer, installed.

----Kubuntu Guest with QEMU installed.

------qemu-Mipsel Debian Guest (of the Kubuntu Guest).

I want the Kubuntu to be able to access the Host network (This was accomplished by using NAT connection on the VM)
And the Kubuntu to be able to connect (SSH and HTTP) to the qemu-mipsel.
I already tried:

**1) The -net hostfwrd flag in qemu command:**

Tried: *adding the following to qemu start machine commmand*

```
"-net user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:22055-:22"
```

Result: *SSH from Kubuntu simply hangs, same for netcat on another port.*

**2) Adding a TAP interface and bridging it**

Tried: *(followed https://blog.elastocloud.org/2015/07/qemukvm-bridged-network-with-tap.html with adjustment to my interface)

Following commands:

```
  #sudo ip link add br0 type bridge

  #sudo ip addr flush dev ens33

  #sudo ip link set ens33 master br0

  #sudo ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user $(whoami)
```

and adding this to the qemu running command:

```
"-netdev tap,id=network0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no"*
```

Result: *Kubuntu machine does not connect to the internet nor to the qemu-mipsel.*

I'm adding here the **ip a** results in case those can help to solve the problem.
[Kubuntu ip a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAqoK.jpg)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Activate promiscuous mode for bridged adapter in Vmware.

Vmware settings -> Network -> Bridged adapter -> Advanced
  -> Promiscuous mode: allow all